# ¿Cómo cambiar el color de un button en JavaFX al momento de hacer :hover?

Tags: java, css, javafx, scenebuilder

he intentado cambiar el color de mi botón pero no sé por qué no funciona.
Iré al grano. El código de mi diseño fxml del botón es el siguiente:

```
<Button id="btnSubmit" layoutX="72.0" layoutY="440.0" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#onSubmit" prefHeight="40.0" prefWidth="300.0" style="-fx-background-color: #bec092; -fx-background-radius: 50px;" text="INICIAR SESIÓN">
           <font>
              <Font size="16.0" />
           </font>
</Button>
```

Bien, ahora, para que mi botón cambie de color en hover, lo que hago es mandar a llamar los estilos desde una carpeta. Mi código principal es este (evitaré detalles innecesarios):

```
public class Login extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("Login.fxml"));
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);
    
    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/css/Style.css").toExternalForm());
    
   
    stage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();        
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
```

}

Ahora, cuando ejecuto mi programa funciona todo, menos al momento de hacer `:hover` sobre el botón 'INICIAR SESIÓN', ¿alguien sabe qué estoy haciendo mal?

El contenido de `/css/Style.css` es el siguiente:

```
#txt1, #pass1 {
-fx-text-fill: #F8EDEB;
}

.button{
-fx-focus-color: transparent;
-fx-background-insets: 0;
}

#btnSubmit:hover{ /* Esto no funciona, no sé el motivo */
-fx-background-color: #ff0000;
-fx-cursor: hand;
-fx-text-fill: #62152d;    
}

#btnClose:hover {
-fx-cursor: hand;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hice una estructura de cómo organicé mis aplicaciones, y funcionan las hojas de esilo.

```
Login
  css
     estilos.css
  login
     Login.java
  views
     Login.fxml
     Menu.fxml
```

Comment: Tienes que agregar el css primero al anchorPane de tu FXML....eso hara que afecte todo el FXML....luego de alli usa el ejemplo que te di ....eso resuelve todo. El otro asunto es que no uses # para el CSS porque alli tendrias que hacer otra modificacion en tu FXML que no es necesaria. Lo complicas. Utiliza .button:hover que es el que se usa en CSS para afectar a todos los botones...

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de varias manera. Una es creando un archivo CSS con el contenido y vincularlo al componente de interes o si usas FXML es asociarlo con el SceneBuilder.

Dentro del mismo seleccionas el contenedor principal que contiene todos los elementos de tu interfaz ejm botones, textfield....etc, generalmente un AnchorPane, luego le das clic en la parte derecha del sceneBuilder  donde dice **Stylesheets**, de alli buscas tu archivo css y lo aceptas. El efecto es instantaneo.
Ahora el contenido del css para el Boton es el siguiente.

```
.button{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 12px;}

.button:hover{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(73,155,234,0.7) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,0.8) 100%);
-fx-text-fill: white;
-fx-font-weight: bold;
-fx-font-family: "Arial";
-fx-font-size: 14px;}

.button:pressed{
-fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(73,155,234,1) 0%, rgba(32,124,229,1) 100%);}
.button:focused{
-fx-effect:dropshadow( three-pass-box  ,#003399 ,10 , 0.3 , 0.0 , 0.0 );}
```

Aca hay varios efectos, cuando el boton esta normal(.button), cuando pasas el puntero por encima(.button:hover) y cuando presionas el boton(.button:pressed)